# Basch Script to List Directories and files

Tags: bash

I have simple requirement . I want to build a Bash script which will perform below actvity

Step -1 :  Go to Directory 
cd /apps/TalendCloud/TalendRemoteEngine/TalendJobServersFiles/jobexecutions/logs

Step- 2 : Grep the result into a variable  . This will return a directory .
var= $(grep -r "pymts_batch" | awk -F":" '{ print $1 }' | grep "stdOutErr*" | awk -F"/" '{ print $1}' | sort -u | tail -1)

Step -3 : go to directory which retuend in above steps 
cd $var

Step -3 : View the file 
cat stdOutErr_$var.log

Can someone help me here to write a simple bash script

Comment: Why is that question tagged as `xslt` and `xml` if you need help with bash?

Comment: Yes I have removed the TAG - XSLT and XML

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)